# How to check "Type" user passed in custom hook in React typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am creating a custom hook to fetch json from api. I am using this hook for different type of data. So i need to set the type whenever i use this hook. Based on the type I use hook should parse data and return the parsed data which should contain data of our desired type.

```js
const useSearch = <T>(url: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T[]>([])
  const fetchData = React.useCallback(
    (searchText: string): void => {
     fetch(url).then(res=>res.json()).then(({ data }) => {
  //check if T is Type1, Type2, Type3
  // all types parse their data using different functions
  //I need to check the type of T
        setData(parseData(data))
      }).catch(error  z=> {
       console.log(error)
      })
    },
    [],
  )
  return [data, fetchData] as const
}
```

But I am unable to find a way to check the type of T and use the corresponding parsing function.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
type MyDataType = {
  foo: 'bar'
}

type MyOtherDataType = {
  baz: 'biz'
}

function isMyDataType(obj: MyDataType | MyOtherDataType): obj is MyDataType {
  return (obj as MyDataType).foo !== undefined;
}

function isMyOtherDataType(obj: MyDataType | MyOtherDataType): obj is MyOtherDataType {
  return (obj as MyOtherDataType).baz !== undefined;
}

// Now your hook...
const useSearch = <T>(url: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T[]>([])
  const fetchData = React.useCallback(
    (searchText: string): void => {
     fetch(url).then(res=>res.json()).then(({ data }) => {
        if (isMyDataType(data)) {
          // TS will treat data as MyDataType
          myUniqueDataHandler(data);
        } else if (isMyOtherDataType(data)) {
          // TS will treat data as MyOtherDataType
          myOtherUniqueDataHandler(data);
        }
        setData(parseData(data))
      }).catch(error  z=> {
       console.log(error)
      })
    },
    [],
  )
  return [data, fetchData] as const
}
```

Alternatively, you could add a "type" field to the data objects that are returned by your API and have an easy check at runtime. Type predicates have the advantage of being type safe (or, at least, as type safe as your predicates); in other words, TS will treat your data as the type you've narrowed to AND Javascript will perform the same check at runtime so you can run your unique handlers.